# Why is it that if I put "set encoding=utf-8" in my vimrc file, plugins won't load properly?

Tags: vimrc, encoding

Here is my vimrc file:

```
call plug#begin('$HOME/vimfiles/plugged')
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'python-mode/python-mode'
Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator', { 'branch': 'stable'}
Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plug 'octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight'
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'jeaye/color_coded'
call plug#end()

set encoding=utf-8
syntax on colorscheme gruvbox
set backspace=indent,eol,start
inoremap ii <Esc> inoremap II <Esc>
set number
set langmenu=en_US let $LANG = 'en_US'
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
```

This is the error I get with "set encoding=utf-8", after command ":PlugInstall":

[image: error]

I use Windows 10

Edit: Well, interestingly enough, the problem apparently was in the picture I sent, but below the blue rectangle I put, I had the letter "á" in my path and changing that worked.

Comment: If you use `set encoding`, it should be one of the first things in your vimrc.  That changes the _internal_ encoding used for data in Vim.  Changing it after there may already be non-ASCII data in memory is just asking for trouble (crashes, errors, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

From [`:help 'encoding'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27encoding%27):

> NOTE: Changing this option will not change the encoding of the existing text in Vim.  It may cause non-ASCII text to become invalid. It should normally be kept at its default value, or set when Vim starts up.  See [multibyte](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/mbyte.txt.html#multibyte).  To reload the menus see [:menutrans](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/mlang.txt.html#%3Amenutrans).

So either set it at the *first* line, or don't set it at all.